# 全角・半角の区別なく、文字列をスペースで分割して配列としたい。

Tags: php, mysql

失礼します。

`explode()` で半角スペースを区切り文字として入力された文字列を配列に格納しようと思っています。

入力された文字列：「り す」 
配列：(［0］り［1］す)

上のような状態に持って行きたいです。 
伝わっているでしょうか？

`explode()` を使用している部分のコードはこちらです。

```
//三項演算子で検索文字列の有無を判定し処理
$data = isset($_POST['data']) ? trim($_POST['data']) : '';
//OR検索
$query = 'SELECT * FROM goods WHERE ';  //クエリ前半
$sql ="";
if($data){
    $count = 1; //カウントを１にしておく
    //全角スペースはmb_convert_kana()関数で半角スペースに変換
    $datalist = mb_convert_kana($data, 's');
    //print $datalist.'<br />';
    //複数キーワードでの検索
    //if(stristr($datalist," ")){
        //検索ワードをスペースで分割して配列に格納
        $keyword = explode(" ",$datalist);
```

コメントアウトの部分は確認用だったり必要か不要かが個人的に曖昧なものを残してあるだけなので無視してくださって構わないかと思います。

現在の状態では、「り す」と入力すると配列の中身は([0]り す)となってしまいます。

なお、文字コードセットはUTF8の状態でファイルを保存してあります。
MySQL が UTF8 で文字化けしてしまうということもあるので、これも原因なのではと思っていますが解決法が見つかりません。

どこが間違っているでしょうか？ 
よろしくお願いします。

念の為に全コードを載せておきます。

```
<?php
//  HTTPヘッダーで文字コードを指定
header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8");
?>
<?php

//session_start();

//h()関数の読み込み
require_once 'lib/h.php';
//checkinput()関数の読み込み
require_once 'lib/checkinput.php';

//POSTされたデータのチェック
$_POST = checkinput($_POST);

//三項演算子で検索文字列の有無を判定し処理
$data = isset($_POST['data']) ? trim($_POST['data']) : '';
//OR検索
$query = 'SELECT * FROM goods WHERE ';  //クエリ前半
$sql ="";
if($data){
    $count = 1; //カウントを１にしておく
    //全角スペースはmb_convert_kana()関数で半角スペースに変換
    $datalist = mb_convert_kana($data, 's');
    //print $datalist.'<br />';
    //複数キーワードでの検索
    //if(stristr($datalist," ")){
        //検索ワードをスペースで分割して配列に格納
        $keyword = explode(" ",$datalist);
        //print_r ($keyword);
        //配列の数を数える
        $count = count($keyword);
        //空スペースで区切られた数によってSQL文を組み立てる
        for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){//配列の数だけ繰り返す
            if($i!="0"){
                $sql = $sql." OR";
            }
        $sql = $sql." name LIKE :keyword ";
        }
    //}
}else{
    $count = 0;
}
//SQL文準備
$query = $query.$sql;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
               "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ja" lang="ja">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="content-script-type" content="text/javascript" />
<meta http-equiv="content-style-type" content="text/css" />
<!--  StyleSheet記述
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
StyleSheet記述  -->
<!-- PAGE TITLE -->
<title>ページタイトル</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(!empty($datalist)){

    try{
        $username = "root";
        $password = "root";
        $pdo = new PDO(
            'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=shop',
            $username,
            $password,
            array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

        //プリペアドステートメントのエミュレーションを無効にする
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
        //エラーが発生した場合、例外がスローされるようにする
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        //検索結果
        if($datalist <> ""){//検索窓が空なら検索しない
            //単ワードでの検索時
            if($count == 1){
                $datalist2 = '%'.$datalist.'%'; //検索文字列を%検索文字%とする
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM goods WHERE name LIKE :datalist");
                $stmt->bindParam(':datalist',$datalist2,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->execute(
                        );
                $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            }//OR検索時
            elseif($count > 1){
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
                for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){ //検索ワードの数だけ繰り返す
                    $keyword2[$i] = '%'.$keyword.'%';   //検索ワード1つ1つを%検索文字%にする
                    $holder = ':keyword'.$i;    //ホルダー用
                    $stmt->bindParam(':holder',$keyword2[$i],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                }
                $stmt->execute(
                        );
                $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }
        }


        if(count($result) == 0){
            print '<p>「'.h($data).'」はデータベースに登録がありません</p>';
        }else{
            print '<p>「'.h($data).'」はデータベースに登録がありました</p>';
?>
            <p>検索結果</p>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <th>商品名</th>
                <th>価格</th>
            </tr>

<?php

            foreach ($result as $row){
?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php print h($row['name']) ?></td>
                <td><?php print h($row['price']) ?></td>
            </tr>
<?php
            }
            print '</table>';
        }

//接続でいない場合、PDOException例外がスローされるのでキャッチする
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        print 'エラーが発生しました。。　内容：' . h($e->getMessage());
    }
}
?>
<p>検索したい文字列を入力</p>
<form action="list_s.php" method="POST" >
<input type="search" name ="data">
<input type="submit" value="検索">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: タイトルを少しわかりやすいように変更しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

今だ解決には至っていませんが、新しく質問を投げるためにここで今までの回答をまとめさせていただきます。

まずKID the Euforiaさんにご指摘頂いたとおりにコードを直したところ、エラーが発生してしまいました。

次にHiroshi Yamamotoさんにご指摘頂いたとおりにコードを書いたところ、問題なく動きました。

話し合いの末環境の方に問題がある可能性が高いとのことでしたので、別に質問を投げさせていただきたいと思います。
回答を下さった皆様ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

まふゆさんのコードを実行してみても問題が再現しませんでしたので、想像での回答となります。
おそらく、non-breaking space(`\xA0`)が入りこんでいるのではないかと考えました。

それを取り除くことで解決する方法を以下に提示いたします。

`mb_convert_kana` している箇所を下記のようにしてみてください。

```
$delimiter = "\x20";
$datalist = preg_replace('/[\x{a0}\x{3000}]/u', $delimiter, $data);
```

また `explode` している箇所を下記のように変更してください。

```
$keyword = explode($delimiter, $datalist);
```

コードで解決するには以上のようになるかと思います。
ただし、 `preg_replace` は重い関数なのでどうしても…という場合以外は避けた方がよいかもしれません。

Comment: 文字列を入れるところに配列を入れようとしているという旨のエラーが出てしまいました。

Answer (score 1):

回答のつもりではないです。要素の整理だけ。単純化しましょうよ。

たぶん、エンコードの問題と思いますが・・・
とりあえず `var_dump()` でいちいち変数をダンプしていくことかな・・・

str_split.php:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8");
// ---------------
$data1 = 'あおげば　とおとし わがしの なんとか';
$data2 = mb_convert_kana($data1, 's', 'UTF-8');
$data3 = explode(" ", $data2);
// ---------------
echo '$data1: '; var_dump( $data1);
echo '<br/>$data2: '; var_dump( $data2);
echo '<br/>$data3: '; var_dump( $data3);
?>
```

Output:

```
$data1: string(53) "あおげば　とおとし わがしの なんとか" 
$data2: string(51) "あおげば とおとし わがしの なんとか" 
$data3: array(4) { 
        [0]=> string(12) "あおげば" 
        [1]=> string(12) "とおとし" 
        [2]=> string(12) "わがしの" 
        [3]=> string(12) "なんとか" 
}
```

Comment: 上記のコードをそのまま試したところ、Output通りの結果になりました。
ということはmysql側の問題でしょうか？
エンコードの問題というものについてはいまいち理解ができていないので調べてみたいと思います。

Comment: エンコードの問題を回避するためには、アプリ全体で使うエンコードを統一するようにしなければなりません。（今回はまだエンコードの問題と決まった訳ではありません）ちぐはぐだと、中間で変換処理が必要になります。今回は、DB の検索結果をPHPに受け取った時点で、PHPが想定しているエンコードと違う可能性があったので、 `var_dump()` で毎回プリントアウトしてみた方がいいと考えました。エンコードが想定外なら、そこで日本語文字が出ない筈ですからね。上記のコードで、質問内コードと違うのは、`mb_convert_kana()` に、 `'UTF-8'` を渡しているところですので、元のコードにも足してみてどうなるか見てみるのも良いと思います。

Comment: このコメントを確認する前に、データベースを1から作り直そうと思いデータベース(この段階でutf8を指定)とテーブルまでは作りました。set names utf8;で指定してから、insert文でデータを入れようとしたところnameの部分でエラーが出ました。試しにset names sjis;と指定して同じ文を実行したところ成功しました。
my.cnfで文字コードの設定をするとの事だったので調べてみたのですが、my.cnfが存在しませんでした。自分で作ることもできるらしいのですが、どこに作って内容はどうすればいいのかがさっぱりわからない状況です。

Comment: 「insert文でデータを入れようとしたところnameの部分でエラーが出ました。」→それはSQL文のほうが既に sjis エンコードだからだと思います。このコメントで初めて分かったことは、まふゆさんが Windows 環境にあり、メモ帳などで編集したファイルは sjis がデフォルトとなりうる環境ということです。SQLファイルのエンコードにも気をつけてください。 my.cnf については、 widows 環境は私もわからないので、別の質問で投げてしまってもいいと思います。